# Error install MySQL: Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'

Tags: mysql

I can't install MySQL in Ubuntu 14.04, because it always gets stuck in:

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
...
2014-12-19 20:15:06 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-12-19 20:15:06 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-12-19 20:15:06 11693 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'

lqqqqqqqqqqqqqu Configuring mysql-server-5.6 tqqqqqqqqqq
x                                                                                                                                                                                                                  x
x Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                                                                                                                                                                 x
x                                                                                                                                                                                                                  x
x An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.  x
x                                                                                                                                                                                                                  x
x You should check the account's password after the package installation.                                                                                                                                          x
x                                                                                                                                                                                                                  x
x Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.6/README.Debian file for more information.
```

I have tried uninstall all packages of MySQL:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server-5.6
apt-get purge mysql-client-5.6
apt-get purge mysql-common
rm -rf /var/log/mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

and remove the temporal dir of dpkg:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
rm *
apt-get update
```

or copy the file errmsg.sys:

```
cp /usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys
sudo chown mysql:mysql /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys
```

I uninstall tomcat7, apache2, php, and always get error in the installation of MySQL.
I've tried to fix it for days. How could fix it?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304353/6533

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tar.gz tarball and then follow below instruction to install. See the instruction from MySQL:

```
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -g mysql mysql
shell> cd /usr/local
shell> gunzip < /path/to/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz | tar xvf -
shell> ln -s full-path-to-mysql-VERSION-OS mysql
shell> cd mysql
shell> chown -R mysql .
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
shell> chown -R root .
shell> chown -R mysql data
shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here is what I usually do to install `MySQL server` on ubuntu:

First I make sure that my system is up to date by updating everything:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I get the `.deb` file with `wget`. You can specify the version you want by getting the link from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/):

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
```

Then you will want to install that package by running the following command (make sure you are in the folder containing the `.deb` file):

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
```

Next, run system update again, and after that install `mysql-server`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If that works, you should be able to run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and install and configure your `MariaDB Server`.

See if this works for you and let me know if you still get the same error.

Comment: Just noticed it's been 9 years since OP posted this. It is surely a resolved issue, so the community can mark this as closed?

Comment: `mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb` is from 2015, I doubt that this is still working